# Ignore style.css when website viewed from a mobile device

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Basically wordpress will always look for `style.css` for CSS rules.

I want to create a responsive theme and I would like to write the `media-queries` in a separate styleheet.

Is there a way where if I view the website from a mobile device, then wordpress looks into this new stylesheet rather than `style.css`?

Comment: why not `<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

Make a new .css and inherit it to style.css file and do whatever you possibly can in child class

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file example.css and call it into your header and write your css with media query. Remember one thing example.css must **call (declare)** under the **main css (style.css)**.

Here is the exmaple for 730 screen size css.

https://www.geraldinemiskin.com/730.css